# Get Boost deadline_timer native file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux, boost

AFAIK `deadline_timer` in Linux is created using [timerfd_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) - which is a file descriptor.
`boost` provides *native()* function for most of its *fd* wrappers;

- `boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor`
- `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`
- ...

Which are also *file descriptors*.
I would like to

1. Use `boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::steady_clock>`
2. Set its native *fd* to `TFD_CLOEXEC`

But `boost` don't provide a *native()* function for `boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::steady_clock>`.

1. Why?
2. Can I somehow achieve that?

---------------------- Test ----------------------
Code example for `fork()`. In `fork()` the `fd` is passed to the son.
When I call some `exec()` function from the son - the `fd` isn't passed to the new process, as @nos said.
For only `fork()`ed process, I would need to use [notify_fork](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/notify_fork.html) as @sehe suggested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {

    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer deadlineTimer(ioService);

    std::string who;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        // Parent
        who = "father, pid " + std::to_string(getpid()) + ", son pid: " + std::to_string(pid);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // Child
        who = "son, pid " + std::to_string(getpid());
        // Call some `exec()` here
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << who << ", waiting..." << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I checked the `fd`s both from `proc` and with `lsof`:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ ll /proc/48564/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 cgs cgs  0 Dec 19 10:40 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 cgs cgs  0 Dec 19 10:40 ../
lrwx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:40 0 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:40 1 -> /dev/pts/29
l-wx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:40 2 -> /dev/pts/31
lrwx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:40 3 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:40 4 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:40 5 -> anon_inode:[timerfd]
me@ubuntu:~$ ll /proc/48568/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 cgs cgs  0 Dec 19 10:41 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 cgs cgs  0 Dec 19 10:41 ../
lrwx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:41 0 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:41 1 -> /dev/pts/29
l-wx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:41 2 -> /dev/pts/31
lrwx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:41 3 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:41 4 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 cgs cgs 64 Dec 19 10:41 5 -> anon_inode:[timerfd]
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I want to prevent timerfd to be inherited to `fork()'ed` process

Comment: Use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/notify_fork.html  as I linked on the answer yesterday.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::steady_clock>` is not a file descriptor.

On linux, the `io_service` you associate with a `waitable_timer` is (normally, as far as I can tell) a timerfd. There's a single timerfd used to maintain all timers. I cannot see any api to access that file descriptor.

That one file descriptor is already created with TFD_CLOEXEC if the kernel supports it, by this code:

```
int epoll_reactor::do_timerfd_create()
{
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_TIMERFD)
# if defined(TFD_CLOEXEC)
  int fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TFD_CLOEXEC);
# else // defined(TFD_CLOEXEC)
  int fd = -1;
  errno = EINVAL;
# endif // defined(TFD_CLOEXEC)

  if (fd == -1 && errno == EINVAL)
  {
    fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
    if (fd != -1)
      ::fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
  }
```

Comment: Note also [notify_fork](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/notify_fork.html) which is public interface to manage "hidden" fds used by Asio service implementations

Comment: @hudac Remember that fork() is not exec(). TFD_CLOEXEC  does not close the descriptor on fork().  You can destroy the `ioService` in your child though (your ioService is of no use if you anyway  would forcibly close its eventfd), to also close the eventfd.  Or if you do eventually call exec(), it will be closed.

Comment: You're right. I got confsued with `fork()` and `exec()`. Thanks.

Comment: @nos I realize this is very late to the party, but do you know why asio chose to go with 1 single fd for all timers vs using 1 per timer using timerfd?